# Logging in to ubuntu with lid closed

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, power-management

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad T490 that I have wiped and installed ubuntu 20.04 on. Everything works well and I created a setup where I used three external monitors and just leave the laptop lid closed.

This is done using one monitor via USB-C and two via the other USB-C via a Lenovo Thinkpad USB-C Dock Gen 2 (where I also have my keyboard etc connected). All these pieces of hardware work together and there are no issues when the laptop is on.

Now, the issue I have is that when I boot the computer, I don't get the login screen on any of my external monitors and I have to open the laptop lid to be able to log in. As soon as I open the laptoplid the keyboard will work and I can see the login screen on the laptop monitor and log in. As soon as I log in the laptop screen goes black (because I have disabled it) and the three external monitors kick in.

Is there a way I can fix this so that I don't have to open up the laptop every time I boot the computer?

Comment: Did You find a solution, yet? I experience the same problem, just another brand (Tuxedo) of notebook.